# JavaScript - Click on each button from code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, loops, button, click

I'm trying to do the following exercise. I would like from Chrome dev console to loop through all buttons that belong to one class and click on each one.
It's a bot like script on the page where I don't know the source. Probably it's a bad question... please do not kick me too much.

the code is following, but click is performed only on the first element:

```
Clicker();

function Clicker ()
{
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');
    for (var i = 0; i <= buttons.length; i++) {
        if(buttons[i])
        {
            if(buttons[i].firstChild.nodeValue)
            {
                if(!buttons[i].disabled)
                {
                    buttons[i].click();
                }   
            }
        }   
    }

    return 'execution complete';
}
```

buttons are written in following way:

```
<button class="myclass" data-action="perfom_job.perform_job">
        Perform Some Job
</button>
<button class="myclass" data-action="perfom_job.perform_job">
        Perform Some Job
</button>
<button class="myclass" data-action="perfom_job.perform_job">
        Perform Some Job
</button>
<button class="myclass" data-action="perfom_job.perform_job">
        Perform Some Job
</button>
```

If I insert buttons[i] into console.log(), the right button is viewed in element inspector.
Which problem could be?

The clicked button become

```
<button class="myclass" disabled="">
   Perform Some Job
</button>
```

#### Update 1

I tried also to make the function like that

```
Clicker();

function Clicker ()
{
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');
    var enabled_buttons = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        if(buttons[i])
        {
            if(buttons[i].firstChild.nodeValue)
            {
                if(!buttons[i].disabled)
                {
                    enabled_buttons.push(buttons[i]);
                }   
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(enabled_buttons.length);
    if(enabled_buttons.length > 0)
    {
        enabled_buttons[0].click();
        Clicker();
    }
}
```

With the result that it goes in infinite loop when it access to the function recursively, he do not see less enabled elements after click.

#### Update 2

I made a little setup using Selenium and my Visual Studio Community 2017 and tried to make the same thing with Microsoft Edge automation, in the way to get error more clearly!

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver())
{
    driver.Url = txtUrl.Text;

    IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> query = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("myclass"));

    foreach(IWebElement elem in query)
    {
        elem.Click();        
    }  
}
```

The first element inside the loop is ok, for the second one I'm getting:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Element is obscured'
```

#### Update 3

This kind of error was caused due to the issue when browser is not able to navigate correctly to the element. Please see my reply on how i have resolved it

Comment: How are you determining only first one is clicked?

Comment: I see it on the page buttons changes to disabled

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) because your script works (even with the "out of bounds" `for` condition): https://jsfiddle.net/Lwohsk4s/

Comment: The code you are showing doesn't show you disabling a button, ie you do not have anything like `buttons[i].disabled=true`

Comment: The problem that i don't know the code behind. I just have to perform testing with scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I had to leave the Idea to use chrome's console with javascript pasted code for this kind of job. I opted to Visual Studio Community 2017 C# + Selenium WebDriver + ChromeDriver

Here is the working code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

namespace DefaultNameSpace
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            //I have used my Chrome's default profile. The path is for MacOSX
            options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=/Users/<user name>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default");
            options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");

            string s;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Command:");
            while (true)
            {
                s = Console.ReadLine();
                if (s.ToLower() == "exit")
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options))
                    {
                        driver.Url = s;
                        Clicker(driver);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Execution complete");
                }
            }

        }

        private static void Clicker(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> query = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(myclass));

            foreach (IWebElement elem in query)
            {
                if (elem.Enabled && elem.Text.Trim() == "Button text")
                {
                    try
                    {
                      //go to the page top
                      IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
                      jse.ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0,0)", "");

                      //go to button and make click
                      Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
                      actions.MoveToElement(elem).Click().Perform();

                      Clicker(driver);
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                      string log = ex.ToString();
                   }
                   finally
                   {
                        //Clicker(driver);   
                   }
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Clicker() {
    var buttons = $('button.myclass');
    $.each(buttons, function () {
        if (!$(this).is(":disabled")) {
            $(this).click();
        }
    });

    return 'execution complete';
}
```

may be it helps you

Comment: Hello. I'm doing reverse engineering on existing working page. I don't have to add any handler to existing elements. I just need to fire click on each button element to make a bot.

Comment: I'm sorry.. It's not me put -1 to you...  this code works in same way, as mine. Only the first element changes his state.